# pandas merge performance warning

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using recursively in a for loop the following command

```py
df_out = pd.merge(df_out, tmp, on='Date', how='outer', sort="false", copy="false")
```

But I'm getting many times the following alert:

```
C:\Users\endys\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:121: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
```

How can I change the code according to the alert's suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
dfs = []
for ...:
    tmp = ...
    dfs.append(tmp)
df_out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Just like that. :)

Comment: are my options for my purpose (on='Date', how='outer', sort="false", copy="false") supported from "append" and "concat"?

Comment: `pd.concat` supports `join='outer'` (that's actually the default). You can also provide it `sort=False` and `copy=False`. I'm not sure about `on` tho, maybe there are other parameters for that.

Comment: unfortunately it seems "on" parameter is not supported by "concat"... https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html